# How do I make it so the user does not lose a life when entering an invalid character in this hangman game?

Tags: python

Here's the code I have:

```
if letter_user not in letters_word:
      mistakes += 1
      wrong_letters.append(letter_user)
if letter_user not in alphabet:
      print('Please only enter ONE letter.')
```

I've created a list of the alphabet and if the users guess is not in that list, then they will get the warning 'Please only enter ONE letter.', however the 'mistakes' counter, still goes up, thus leading in the user losing a life, which I do not want.

How do I make it so the user does not lose a life when entering an invalid character in this hangman game?

Here's my full code:

```
# importing wordbank
import random
from wordbankcool import wordbank

# hangman graphics
hangman_graphics = ['_',
                    '__',
                    '__\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O',
                    '__\n |\n O\n |',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ ',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/',
                    '__\n |\n O\n/|\ \n/ \ '
                    ]

# code is inside while loop
playagain = 'Y'
while playagain == 'Y':

    # alphabet
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    # basic functions of the game
    mistakes = 0
    letters_guessed = []
    mistakes_allowed = len(hangman_graphics)

    # selecting a random word for the user to guess
    word = random.choice(wordbank)

    # letters user has guessed + guessed incorrectly stored in lists
    letters_word = list(word)
    wrong_letters = []

    print()

    # amount of letters the word has
    print('The word has {} letters'.format(len(letters_word)))

    # while loop which will run until the the number of mistakes = number of mistakes allowed
    while mistakes < mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Incorrect guesses: ', end='')
        for letter in wrong_letters:
            print('{}, '.format(letter), end='')
        print()
        print('Guesses left: {}'.format(mistakes_allowed - mistakes))
        letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()

    # checking if the letter has been guessed before
        while letter_user in letters_guessed or letter_user in wrong_letters:
            print()
            print('You have already guessed this letter, guess a different one.')
            letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ')

    # increasing amount of mistakes if the letter that has been guessed is not in the word
        if letter_user not in letters_word:
            mistakes += 1
            wrong_letters.append(letter_user)
        if letter_user not in alphabet:
            print('Please only enter ONE letter.')

        print()

    # showing how many letters the user has/has not guessed
        print('Word: ', end='')

    # if letter is in word, its added to letters guessed
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter_user == letter:
                letters_guessed.append(letter_user)

    # replace letters that haven't been guessed with an underscore
        for letter in letters_word:
            if letter in letters_guessed:
                print(letter + ' ', end='')
            else:
                print('_ ', end='')

        print()

    # hangman graphics correlate with amount of mistakes made
        if mistakes:
            print(hangman_graphics[mistakes - 1])
        print()
        print('-------------------------------------------')  # seperator

    # ending: user wins
        if len(letters_guessed) == len(letters_word):
            print()
            print(f'You won! The word was {word}!')
            print()
            playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
            if playagain == 'Y':
                word = random.choice(wordbank)
                break
            elif playagain == 'N':
                break

    # ending: user loses
    if mistakes == mistakes_allowed:
        print()
        print('Unlucky, better luck next time!')
        print()
        print(f'The word was {word}.')
        print()
        playagain = input('Play again? (Y/N) ').upper()
        if playagain == 'Y':
            word = random.choice(wordbank)
```

Comment: If you want yo give countdown mistake then make 2 variable, one for count and one for limit and set your limit of attempt use while loop. If playerinput != Correct answer and count < limit then count += 1 like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the check for bad input up so that it happens sooner. Then you can use the [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement - this basically jumps to the end of the loop, skipping everything after it.

```
if letter_user not in alphabet:
    print('Please only enter ONE letter.')
    continue
if letter_user not in letters_word:
    mistakes += 1
    wrong_letters.append(letter_user)
....
```

However, you already have an input loop, so you can check it there.

```
while True:
    letter_user = input('Guess a letter: ').lower()
    if letter_user not in alphabet:
        print('Please only enter ONE letter.')
    elif letter_user in letters_guessed or letter_user in wrong_letters:
        print('You have already guessed this letter, guess a different one.')
    else:
        break
```